# Add to Dictionary<string, string> using foreach

Tags: c#

what is the best way to ensure that optionValue is always unique in the following scenario?

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (string optionKey in i.options.Keys)
    {
       string optionValue = i.options.Values.ToString();
       Dict.Add(optionKey, optionValue);
    }
```

**EDIT**: i.options contains a key and a value pair. I need to ensure that for each key the corresponding value is added to the dictionary

**EDIT2**: corrected order of Dict.Add(optionKey, optionValue)

Comment: What is `i.options`?  It appears to be a Dictionary and it appears that you are flipping the key and value going to `Dict`.  Also, if it is a Dictionary, won't `i.options.Values.ToString()` return "IEnumerable&lt;T&gt;"

Comment: According to MSDN, the dictionary will throw an exception if the key already exists.  You can either test for it or rely (BAD) on the exception being thrown.  

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k.aspx

Comment: Did you mix optionValue and optionKey by accident?

Comment: @tafoo85 Yes, I currently get that exception. Please see my edits above

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "c# " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 2):

Just test for it:

```
if(!Dict.ContainsKey(optionValue))
   Dict.Add(optionValue, optionKey)
```

Based on your variable names *it looks like* you have key and value reversed though, if `optionKey` is your lookup key it should be:

```
Dict.Add(optionKey, optionValue);
```

Comment: This approach can lead to lost data.  A custom <T, T> dictionary would allow preserving all options and keys, regardless of duplicate fields.

Answer (score 1):

In a Dictionary all keys are unique. If you want to prevent an exception when adding entries to the Dictionary, use

```
if (!Dict.ContainsKey(optionKey)) {
  Dict.Add(optionKey, optionValue);
} else {
  Debug.Print("Key '"+optionKey+"' already exists");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A cursory browsing of the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htszx2dy.aspx) documentation reveals that you can use the obvious method `ContainsKey(string)` to check to see if a dictionary contains a certain key.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you want to handle duplicates.

E.g "last one wins"

```
foreach(...)
{
    // Will overwrite an existing key
    Dict[optionValue] = optionKey;
}
```

"First one wins":

```
foreach(...)
{
    if (!Dict.ContainsKey(optionValue)) Dict.Add(optionValue, optionKey);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (string optionKey in i.options.Keys)
{
   string optionValue = i.options.Values.ToString();
   if(!Dict.ContainsValue(optionValue))
       Dict.Add(optionValue, optionKey);
}
```

See
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: this still results in an error that "An item with the same key has already been added."

Comment: Just add a Key uniqueness condition:
`if(!Dict.ContainsKey(optionKey))
  if(!Dict.ContainsValue(optionValue))
    Dict.Add(optionValue, optionKey)`

Comment: I get the same error as above since the code is always picking the same optionValue

Answer (score 0):

Other folks have been suggesting that you simply test to see if the key exists, and skip adding if it does.  However, this may lead to lost data.  You should create a custom class or type and use that with your dictionary like so:

> public Dictionary< Guid, CustomObjectOrType > Dict = new
>   Dictionary< Guid, CustomObjectOrType >();

This way you can ensure that each key is unique (a Guid) while preserving all option values and option keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just worried about exceptions, then just use the item property:

Dict[optionValue] = optionKey;

MSDN: If the specified key is not found, a get operation throws a KeyNotFoundException, and a set operation creates a new element with the specified key.

Or if you really want to do the check, use the ContainsKey method to check

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx